# How to apply dynamic style for the PrimeNg table rows?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have the **MyObject.ts** file as

```
name:String
rowStyle:String
```

and **MyComponent.ts** file as

```
myObject1:MyObject=new MyObject();
myObject2:MyObject=new MyObject();

myObjectList:MyObject[]=[];

myObject1.name="Red Color Row"
myObject1.rowStyle="background-color:red"
myObject2.name="Bold Font"
myObject2.rowStyle="font-weight:bold"

myObjectList.push(myObject1);
myObjectList.push(myObject2);
```

and **MyComponent.html** file as

```
<p-table [value]="myObjectList">
     <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Styles</th>
            </tr>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-listObject>
            <tr>
              <td>listObject.name</td>
              <td>listObject.rowStyle</td>
            </tr>
      </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Now how can I apply the styles specified in the rowStyle attribute to the rows of the table?

Comment: Try this `<tr [style]="listObject.rowStyle">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<tr style="{{listObject.rowStyle}}">
```